# why are special character not alloed in email address

Tags: email

I was just curious about why only a few special character are not allowed in email address.
Except a few special character like ".", "_" etc most of special character characters bot allowed. is this a technology constraint or just a convention without any reason ?

Answer (score 4):

It's a blatant falsity that is unjustly imposed by overzealous email regexps.

Almost all characters can be used in email addresses.
`"abc def+ghi/jkl@mno*pqr"@localhost` is a valid email address.

Even without quoting, `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@hi `` is valid.

Comment: I'm confused. The OP said "only a few special characters are *not* allowed", and you say "Almost all characters can be used". What was your answer trying to say exactly?

Comment: @Ken: You're misreading his poor English.  He says later, `most of special character characters bot allowed`

Comment: Yep, for example many "overzealous email regexps" (which some web sites use to validate account creations) fail to recognize valid e-mail addresses with address tags (user+tag@domain.com).

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Glad I didn't downvote. :) I missed the "bot allowed" that followed.

Answer (score 1):

Check [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) for details on the specification of internet email addresses.

Comment: RFC 2822 has been obsoleted by [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1).